# Why do I get a "referenced before assignment" error when assigning to a global variable in a function?

Tags: python, global-variables

In Python, I'm getting the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'total' referenced before assignment
```

At the start of the file (before the function where the error comes from), I declare `total` using the `global` keyword. Then, in the body of the program, before the function that uses `total` is called, I assign it to 0. I've tried setting it to 0 in various places (including the top of the file, just after it is declared), but I can't get it to work.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you declaring global in the function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError on local variable when reassigned after first use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-on-local-variable-when-reassigned-after-first-use)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

I think you are using 'global' incorrectly. See [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement). You should declare variable without global and then inside the function when you want to access global variable you declare it `global yourvar`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

total

def checkTotal():
    global total
    total = 0
```

See this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

total = 0

def doA():
    # not accessing global total
    total = 10

def doB():
    global total
    total = total + 1

def checkTotal():
    # global total - not required as global is required
    # only for assignment - thanks for comment Greg
    print total

def main():
    doA()
    doB()
    checkTotal()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Because `doA()` does not modify the *global total* the output is 1 not 11.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that you only need the "global" keyword if you assign to the global variable within a local scope. So in your example, the global declaration is not required in checkTotal().

Comment: Comprehensive answer, and a well-sussed analysis of the essential misunderstanding behind the question.

Comment: I meant it might be worth *noting* of course! Still can't edit comments without delete-readd. :(

Comment: when declaring a global variable, I had to assign a value to it (I did `glob_val=None`, IOW, I wasn't able to declare it without a value assignment

Answer (score 7):

My Scenario

```
def example():
    cl = [0, 1]
    def inner():
        #cl = [1, 2] # access this way will throw `reference before assignment`
        cl[0] = 1 
        cl[1] = 2   # these won't

    inner()
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to mention that you can do like this for the function scope

```
def main()

  self.x = 0

  def increment():
    self.x += 1
  
  for i in range(5):
     increment()
  
  print(self.x)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
def inside():
   global var
   var = 'info'
inside()
print(var)

>>>'info'
```

problem ended

Comment: It would be helpful to explain how your code works by a simple explanation or a comment

Comment: The accepted answer seems to have covered the usage of `global` already.

Comment: This simply repeats what the accepted answer says, but as Anurag AS mentions, there is no explanation. And as General Grievance says, if the accepted answer already covers the usage of global, then why bother posting an unexplained bit of code that adds nothing to the conversation?