# Unbound Local Error

Tags: python, global-variables

I keep getting an unbound local error with the following code in python:

```
xml=[]       
global currentTok
currentTok=0                     

def demand(s):
    if tokenObjects[currentTok+1].category==s:
        currentTok+=1
        return tokenObjects[currentTok]
    else:
        raise Exception("Incorrect type")

def compileExpression():
    xml.append("<expression>")
    xml.append(compileTerm(currentTok))
    print currentTok
    while currentTok<len(tokenObjects) and tokenObjects[currentTok].symbol in op:
        xml.append(tokenObjects[currentTok].printTok())
        currentTok+=1
        print currentTok
        xml.append(compileTerm(currentTok))
    xml.append("</expression>")

def compileTerm():
    string="<term>"
    category=tokenObjects[currentTok].category
    if category=="integerConstant" or category=="stringConstant" or category=="identifier":
        string+=tokenObjects[currentTok].printTok()
        currentTok+=1
    string+="</term>"
    return string

compileExpression()
print xml
```

The following is the exact error that I get:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currentTok' referenced before assignment.
```

This makes no sense to me as I clearly initialize `currentTok` as one of the first lines of my code, and I even labeled it as `global` just to be safe and make sure it was within the scope of all my methods.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python especially the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the line `global currentTok` into your *function*, not the main module.

```
currentTok=0                     

def demand(s):
    global currentTok
    if tokenObjects[currentTok+1].category==s:
        # etc.
```

The `global` keyword tells your function that it needs to look for that variable in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare it global inside the function definition, not at the global scope.

Otherwise, the Python interpreter sees it used inside the function, assumes it to be a local variable, and then complains when the first thing that you do is reference it, rather than assign to it.