# Why does my if-else statement result in an Unbound Local Error?

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement

When I was writing my code, I ran into an Unbound Local Error when the value should've been assigned within a prior "if" statement :

> UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'b' where it is not associated with a value

```
def find_b(a):
    if a == 1:
        b = 3
    else:
        b += 1
    return b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = 0
    for i in range(0, 2):
        a += 1
        b = find_b(a)
    print(b)
```

I expected b to increment by 1, in this case. However, it caused a Local Unbound Error to occur instead. The only possible solution I saw was to use the global keyword on the variable "b" but since I'm unsure why the error exists, I'd like an explanation.

Comment: There is no assignment to the local variable `b` if it ends up in the `else` block. It doesn't matter what a previous call to the function did

Comment: `b += 1` is not a meaningful statement when you haven't yet assigned a value to `b` in that scope.

Comment: My issue is that when I assign a value to b as 0 within the function, it seems to skip over the "if" statement even when a = 1.

Comment: The if gets skipped on the second loop because a = 2. On the first loop, where a = 1, b will be 3, but you're only printing the result of the final loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unbound Local Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094719/unbound-local-error)

Comment: This is a scope issue and you can find more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp). I flagged this question as a duplicate because it has been asked many times before.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I got by setting b = 0 in the find_b():

```py
In [1]: def find_b(a):
   ...:     b = 0
   ...:     if a == 1:
   ...:         b = 3
   ...:     else:
   ...:         b += 1
   ...:     return b
   ...: 
   ...: if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...:     a = 0
   ...:     for i in range(0, 2):
   ...:         a += 1
   ...:         b = find_b(a)
   ...:     print(b)
   ...: 
1
```

Maybe you want this? Rather than increment 'a' within your for loop, just use 'i'. But perhaps I'm not getting what you want to happen.

```py
In [2]: def find_b(a):
   ...:     b = 0
   ...:     if a == 1:
   ...:         b = 3
   ...:     else:
   ...:         b += 1
   ...:     return b
   ...: 
   ...: if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...:     a = 0
   ...:     for i in range(0, 2):
   ...:         b = find_b(i)
   ...:     print(b)
   ...: 
3
```

Comment: The second thing is what I want to happen, thank you for your answer. One Questions though: why does your first piece of code causes b to be equal to 1.

Comment: See Xnot's comment above. If you're still having a hard time seeing it, work through the steps on paper. Sounds old fashioned, but it can be a great learning/visualization tool.