# Accessing a variable from a defined function in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I have code that looks similar to this

```
v = '0'

def program():
    x = input('1 or 2 ')
    if x == '1':
        print('it is 1')
        v = '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print('it is 2')
        v = '2'

while True:
    program()
    print(v)
```

However, when I run this code the variable 'v' always prints out the default 0.
Why isn't it giving me the variable I assigned it in the function?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: You'll find an excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two variables named `v`:

1. The global level `v=0` declaration at the top.
2. The function declaration of `v` in program.

First of all, you really shouldn't use globals in functions, as it is bad programming practice.  You should pass it as a parameter and return with any other results.

If you really must, you can modify a global variable in a function by first declaring it as a global variable.

Also note that you need to use `raw_input` in Python 2.

```
def program():
    global v
    x = raw_input('1 or 2 ')
    if x == '1':
        print('it is 1')
        v = '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print('it is 2')
        v = '2'
```

[Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: Nice explanation. Good call on the bad practice mention.

Answer (score 2):

Your function manipulates a local copy of variable `v`. If you want to get the value of v after calling `program()`, append `return v` to the end of your function definition.
That is:

```
v = '0'

def program():
    x = input('1 or 2 ')
    if x == '1':
        print('it is 1')
        v = '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print('it is 2')
        v = '2'
    return v

while True:
    v = program()
    print(v)
```

If you don't want to return anything, you can set `v` to the globally declared variable as so:

```
v = '0'

def program():
    x = input('1 or 2 ')
    if x == '1':
        print('it is 1')
        global v
        v = '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print('it is 2')
        global v
        v = '2'

while True:
    program()
    print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement the duplicate flag, here is an explanation with respect to your code:

You need to explicitly tell your method that you want to use the global `v`, otherwise, it will never get updated from what is happening to the `v` within the method scope.

To rectify this, you want to add `global v` inside your method:

```
def program():
    global v
    # rest of your code here
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignments in Python are locally scoped. If you want to manipulate a global state (or an enclosing state) inside of a function, you can wrap that state in a holder and then reference the holder. For example:

```
v = ['0']

def program():
    x = input('1 or 2 ')
    if x == '1':
        print('it is 1')
        v[0] = '1'
    elif x == '2':
        print('it is 2')
        v[0] = '2'

while True:
    program()
    print(v[0])
```

The above segment references an array and manipulates the value inside of the array.

Comment: You might want to explain how one changes the actual id of the variable while the other just modifies the object that the variable is referencing.