# Python local variables behaving strangely

Tags: python, scope

Consider the following code:

```
def g():
    a = {}
    b = 0
    def f():
        a[0] = b
    f()
    print(a)
    return a
a = g()
print(a)
```

It gives the following output when executed:

```
{0: 0}
{0: 0}
```

But if I try to update `b` in `f()` as in

```
def g():
    a = {}
    b = 0
    def f():
        a[0] = b
        b+=1
    f()
    print(a)
    return a
a = g()
print(a)
```

It throws the following error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b' referenced before assignment
```

Is this expected? I need to update `b` inside `f()`. Is that impossible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python

Comment: Rather than trying to solve the apparent problem, I would suggest that you change your strategy so that you don't need to mutate non-local variables. Wherever possible, prefer pure functions. And if you do need to mutate, do it explicitly (passing the variables as function args) rather than indirectly.

Comment: Thanks @FMc, I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: Impressive. Despite that this is a common duplicate, there were *four* duplicate answers marked on this question and *all* of them missed the mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `nonlocal` keyword:

```
def g():
    a = {}
    b = 0
    def f():
        nonlocal b
        a[0] = b
        b+=1
    f()
    print(a)
    return a
a = g()
print(a)
```

This is because `b += 1` is equal to `b = b + 1`, so you're assigning `b` inside of the function `f()`. Even though it's later in the code, this will make it a local variable for the *whole* `f()` function, and thus `a[0] = b` will refer to the local `b` which isn't defined yet. Using `nonlocal` tells the interpreter that there's already a variable `b` and it should be used in the function, instead of creating a new local variable.

Comment: Useful explanation, but I think `nonlocal` is available only in Python 3, which the OP appears not to be using.

Comment: Hi @FMc, I am using python3. The solution works.

Comment: But then the `print a` would raise SyntaxErrors.

Comment: @MSeifert: Edited

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly pass `a` and `b` to your function.

```
def g():
    a = {}
    b = 0
    def f(a, b):
        a[0] = b
        b += 1
        return b
    b = f(a, b)
    return a
```