# Global DataFrame not updated python

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe, global-variables

I have this code:

```
latitude = pd.DataFrame()
longitude = pd.DataFrame()

datasets = []

datasets.append(latitude)
datasets.append(longitude)

def fun(key, job):
    global latitude
    global longitude

    if(key == 'LAT'):
        latitude = job.copy()
    elif(key == 'LON'):
        longitude = job.copy()

for d in datasets:
    print(d.shape)
```

Following this: [Why does assigning to my global variables not work in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python) I have used the global keyword to ensure that the variables are correctly referenced. However, the values are not updated. Any advice? I have already verified that the if statements are correct as I am able to print something in them.

OUTPUT:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 0)
```

Moreover, I am using spyder and I can see that the list contains empty dataframe and also the global variable are empty.

Comment: how did you checked that the values are not updated?? and please add output of your values

Comment: I have edited the question, thank you. @ddor254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

o.k , the problem you have is that you make your program to point to some value in the `datasets.append(latitude)` and when you change the `global latitude` `latitude = job.copy()` , you changing the value of the global variable and not the one in your list `datasets`.

if you want to see the changed value print out `latitude` and you will see that the value has changed. or change the value in `datasets[0]` for latitude value in your loop.

Comment: This solve the problem, however, should the variable in the list be a reference to the actual global variables? @ddor254

Comment: when changing value of the global variable you are changing what it points to. so the reference in the list still points to "old" global variable , but when you assign value to this global variable it now points to other address , which is not updated on the list.