# Trying to change a variable with a function (integer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I want to take a variable with an integer assigned to it then call a function that can just simply add to that variable's number.

This is what I've tried:

```
gold = 0
print(gold)

def addgold(gold):
    gold + 1 = gold

addgold(gold)
print(gold)
```

Comment: (1) you probably meant `gold = gold + 1`, not `gold + 1 = gold` (2) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929777/why-does-assigning-to-my-global-variables-not-work-in-python

Comment: In general you can't do this in Python. `int` objects are immutable. But the correct way to approach this depends on exactly what you are doign

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: The `gold` in the function is an argument, which is like a local variable — it's not the global variable with the same name that you are passing in the call to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to return gold:

```py
gold = 0

print(gold)

def addgold(gold):
    gold = gold + 1
    return gold

gold = addgold(gold)

print(gold)
```

Also to be clear about functions, their parameters and local variables, this code below is exactly the same as the above:

```py
gold = 0

print(gold)

def addgold(foo):       # parameter is now named foo
    foo = foo + 1
    return foo

gold = addgold(gold)

print(gold)
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments say, in general this is a bad thing to do.
However, you can do it this way:

```py
gold = 0

print(gold)

def addgold():
    global gold
    gold += 1 #Same as gold=gold+1

addgold(gold)

print(gold)
```

However it is better in this case to just use `gold += 1` in any place you'd use `addgold()`, as they do the same thing.

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: yeah, I completely agree. But I think it is the closest to what the question was asking

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that you should return the value of your variable in addgold function, then when you call it, gives you a number and you can save it in new variable
like this code :

```
gold= 0
def addgold(gold):
    gold =gold +1
    return gold
new_gold = addgold(gold)
print(new_gold)
```

good luck.