# Confusing change of scope - what's going on?

Tags: python

```
def Test(value):
    def innerFunc():
        print value
    innerFunc()

def TestWithAssignment(value):
    def innerFunc():
        print value
        value = "Changed value"
    innerFunc()

Test("Hello 1")
# Prints "Hello 1"

TestWithAssignment("Hello 2")
# Throws UnboundLocalError: local variable 'value' referenced before assignment
# on the "print value" line
```

Why does the second one fail, given that the only difference is an assignment which comes *after* the print statement? I am pretty confused about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/855493/287976

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that Python wants you to be explicit and you want to be implicit.  The [execution model](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html) that Python uses binds names to the nearest available **enclosing** scope.

```
def Test(value):
    # Local Scope #1
    def innerFunc():
        # Local Scope #2
        print value 
        # No immediate local in Local Scope #2 - check up the chain
        # First find value in outer function scope (Local Scope #1).
        # Use that.
    innerFunc()

def TestWithAssignment(value):
    # Local Scope #1
    def innerFunc():
        # Local Scope #2
        print value 
        # Immediate local variable found in Local Scope #2.
        # No need to check up the chain.
        # However, no value has been assigned to this variable yet.
        # Throw an error.
        value = "Changed value"
    innerFunc()
```

There is not (as far as I know) a way to walk up the scope in Python 2.x - you have `globals()` and `locals()` - but any scopes between the global and the local scope cannot be accessed (if this is not true, I'd *love* to be corrected).

However, you can pass the local variable `value` into your inner local scope:

```
def TestWithAssignment(value):
    def innerFunc(value):
        print value 
        # Immediate local **and assigned now**.
        value = "Changed value"
        # If you need to keep the changed value
        # return value
    innerFunc(value)
    # If you need to keep the changed value use:
    # value = innerFunc(value)
```

In Python 3 you have the new [`nonlocal`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) statement that can be used to refer to the containing scope (Thanks @Thomas K).

```
def TestWithAssignment(value):
    def innerFunc():
        nonlocal value
        print value 
        value = "Changed value"
    innerFunc()
```

Comment: Why/how does python know about the immediate local even though it is assigned later on in the function? This seems like pretty bizarre behavior to me - if "value" is in scope in the first function, I would expect it to be in scope in the second.

Comment: @Sean: From Python 3, you can use `nonlocal value` to bind to its name in the outer scope. But I don't know of any way to access outer scopes like globals() and locals().

Comment: @combatdave - it is scoped in both - the scoping is done first.  The key is in the link I provided "A *block* is a piece of Python program text that is executed as a unit. The following are blocks: a module, a **function body**, and a class definition ... If a local variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks contained within the defining one, **unless a contained block introduces a different binding for the name**."

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```
def Test(value):
    def innerFunc(value):
        print value
    innerFunc(value)
```

Comment: I don't think he's asking how to fix it, but rather why it's broken. Also, you'd have to update `innerFunc` to take value as a parameter for this to work.

Comment: Yeah, there are a few ways that this could be fixed, but I'd like to know how/why the first one works fine and the second one fails.