# Selenium fails to select element by id

Tags: python, selenium

Here is the HTML code of the element:

```
<input maxlength="64" name="pskSecret" class="text" id="pskSecret" value="" size="32" type="text">
```

And here is my python code, which tries to select it:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("pskSecret").clear()
self.driver.find_element_by_id("pskSecret").send_keys(data) # data is variable
```

However I got exception, stating that selenium is unable to locate the element. 
Any ideas what may be causing the problem

Edit: Also the element is inside an iframe, however I'm accessing other elements in it which are working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be when you are going to find element, it could not be load on the DOM due to timing issues. You should try using `WebDriverWait` to wait until element is visible as below :-

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC



wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "pskSecret")))
input.clear()
input.send_keys(data)
```

**Note** :- if this element is inside any frame you need to switch that frame before finding element using `self.driver.switch_to_frame("your frame id or name")`

Comment: Yeah, I'm switching the frames. However for some reason I get "reference before assigment" for input.

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev This is not occurred by selenium code. I think this occurred due to `data` variable.. you are assigning value incorrectly into global variable `data`.. please have a look into this link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment..hope it helps..

Comment: I fixed the error, however now I got 'By' has no attribute 'id'

Comment: it should be `By.ID` instead of `By.Id`

Comment: @Greg Yes..sorry for typo mistake..now updated it.Thanks.:)

Comment: I've also managed to find it in the documentation. I'm testing it now hopefully it will be working.

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev sorry for typo mistake..it should be `By.ID`...:)

Comment: Hmm..  now I got TimeoutException, without any message

Comment: @DeyanGeorgiev make sure first this element inside a frame or outside the frame...