# .split() returning empty results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to split a list that I have converted with str(), but I don't seem to be returning any results?

My code is as follows:

```
import csv

def csv_read(file_obj):
    reader=csv.DictReader(file_obj,delimiter=',')
    for line in reader:
        unique_id.append(line["LUSERFLD4"])
        total_amt.append(line["LAMOUNT1"])
        luserfld10.append(line["LUSERFLD10"])       
        break

    bal_fwd, junk, sdc, junk2, est_read=str(luserfld10).split(' ')

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("UT_0004A493.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_read(f_obj)

print (luserfld10)
print (bal_fwd)
print (sdc)
print (est_read)
```

print (luserfld10) returns ['N | N | Y'] which is correct. (Due to system limitations when creating the csv file, this field holds three separate values)
All variables have been defined and I'm not getting any errors, but my last three print commands are returning empty lists?

I've tried dedenting the .split() line, but then I can unpack only one value.

How do I get them to each return N or Y?

Why isn't it working as it is?

I'm sure it's obvious, but this is my first week of coding and I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere here. Any help (with explanations please) would be appreciated :)

Edit: all defined variables are as follows:

```
luserfld10=[]
bal_fwd=[]
sdc=[]
est_read=[]
```

etc.

File contents I'm not certain how to show? I hope this is okay?

```
LACCNBR,LAMOUNT1,LUSERFLD4,LUSERFLD5,LUSERFLD6,LUSERFLD8,LUSERFLD9,LUSERFLD10
1290,-12847.28,VAAA0022179,84889.363,Off Peak - nil,5524.11,,N | N | N
2540255724,12847.28,VAAA0022179,84889.363,Off Peak - nil,5524.11,,N | N | N
```

Comment: Unless you provide the file contents and the definitions for the variables nobody can reproduce this. If I were you I'd edit this and provide these things.

Comment: Looks like you are split on list instead of string, try `luserfld10[0].split()`

Comment: Is line you are trying to split "N|N|Y"? If yes, then why do you split with ',', you should split wiht '|'

Comment: JimFasarakis-Hilliard - More information added. I hope that's okay?
Skycc - I've tried that now, but am getting the same result.
AdaBorowa - The string has spaces before and after the '|'. I tried using ' | ' but that didn't work either..

Comment: use globals inside of your method.

Comment: @Lafexlos It worked! Thank you so much!! I'm not sure what you mean by local vs global variables though?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python Check this one please. It explains way better than I can for sure. :)

Comment: Your  `csv_read` function doesn't have a `return` statement, so it returns `None`. Why do you have a `break` statement in the `for` loop? Do you only want to read the first line of data from the CSV file? Why do you want to put the data into separate lists: a single list of dictionaries (with each dictionary containing the data you want to keep from each row of the CSV) would be more useful, IMHO.

Comment: I think you will find these articles helpful: [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the `luserfld10` is `['N | N | Y']`

then,

```
luserfld10[0].replace('|', '').split()
```

Result:

```
['N', 'N', 'Y']
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if you fix the `.split` stuff in

```
bal_fwd, junk, sdc, junk2, est_read=str(luserfld10).split(' ')
```

it won't do what you want because it's assigning the results of the split to local names `bal_fwd`, `sdc`, etc, that only exist inside the `csv_read` function, not to the names you defined outside the function in the global scope.

You *could* use `global` statements to tell Python to assign those values to the global names, but it's generally best to avoid using the global statement unless you *really* need it. Also, merely using a `global` statement won't put the string data into your `bal_fwd` list. Instead, it will bind the global name to your string data and discard the list. If you want to put the string into the list you need to `.append` it, like you did with `unique_id`. You don't need `global` for that, since you aren't performing an assignment, you're just modifying the existing list object.

Here's a repaired version of your code, tested with the data sample you posted.

```
import csv

unique_id = []
total_amt = []
luserfld10 = []
bal_fwd = []
sdc = []
est_read = []

def csv_read(file_obj):
    for line in csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=','):
        unique_id.append(line["LUSERFLD4"])
        total_amt.append(line["LAMOUNT1"])
        fld10 = line["LUSERFLD10"]
        luserfld10.append(fld10)

        t = fld10.split(' | ')
        bal_fwd.append(t[0])
        sdc.append(t[1])
        est_read.append(t[2])

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("UT_0004A493.csv") as f_obj:
        csv_read(f_obj)

    print('id', unique_id)
    print('amt', total_amt)
    print('fld10', luserfld10)
    print('bal', bal_fwd)
    print('sdc', sdc)
    print('est_read', est_read)
```

**output**

```
id ['VAAA0022179', 'VAAA0022179']
amt ['-12847.28', '12847.28']
fld10 ['N | N | N', 'N | N | N']
bal ['N', 'N']
sdc ['N', 'N']
est_read ['N', 'N']
```

I should mention that using `t = fld10.split(' | ')` is a bit fragile: if the separator isn't *exactly* `' | '` then the split will fail. So if there's a possibility that there might not be exactly one space either side of the pipe (`|`) then you should use a variation of Jinje's suggestion:

```
t = fld10.replace('|', ' ').split()
```

This replaces all pipe chars with spaces, and then splits on runs of white space, so it's guaranteed to split the subields correctly, assuming there's at least one space or pipe between each subfield (Jinje's original suggestion will fail if both spaces are missing on either side of the pipe).

---

Breaking your data up into separate lists may not be a great strategy: you have to be careful to keep the lists synchronised, so it's tricky to sort them or to add or remove items. And it's tedious to manipulate all the data as a unit when you have it spread out over half a dozen named lists.

One option is to put your data into a dictionary of lists:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint

def csv_read(file_obj):
    data = {
        'unique_id': [],
        'total_amt': [],
        'bal_fwd': [],
        'sdc': [],
        'est_read': [],
    }

    for line in csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=','):
        data['unique_id'].append(line["LUSERFLD4"])
        data['total_amt'].append(line["LAMOUNT1"])
        fld10 = line["LUSERFLD10"]

        t = fld10.split(' | ')
        data['bal_fwd'].append(t[0])
        data['sdc'].append(t[1])
        data['est_read'].append(t[2])

    return data

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("UT_0004A493.csv") as f_obj:
        data = csv_read(f_obj)

    pprint(data)
```

**output**

```
{'bal_fwd': ['N', 'N'],
 'est_read': ['N', 'N'],
 'sdc': ['N', 'N'],
 'total_amt': ['-12847.28', '12847.28'],
 'unique_id': ['VAAA0022179', 'VAAA0022179']}
```

Note that `csv_read` doesn't directly modify any global variables. It creates a dictionary of lists and passes it back to the code that calls it. This makes the code more modular; trying to debug large programs that use globals can become a nightmare because you have to keep track of every part of the program that modifies those globals.

---

Alternatively, you can put the data into a list of dictionaries, one per row.

```
def csv_read(file_obj):
    data = []
    for line in csv.DictReader(file_obj, delimiter=','):
        luserfld10 = line["LUSERFLD10"]
        bal_fwd, sdc, est_read = luserfld10.split(' | ')
        # Put desired data and into a new dictionary
        row = {
            'unique_id': line["LUSERFLD4"],
            'total_amt': line["LAMOUNT1"],
            'bal_fwd': bal_fwd,
            'sdc': sdc,
            'est_read': est_read, 
        }
        data.append(row)
    return data

if __name__=="__main__":
    with open("UT_0004A493.csv") as f_obj:
        data = csv_read(f_obj)

    pprint(data)
```

**output**

```
[{'bal_fwd': 'N',
  'est_read': 'N',
  'sdc': 'N',
  'total_amt': '-12847.28',
  'unique_id': 'VAAA0022179'},
 {'bal_fwd': 'N',
  'est_read': 'N',
  'sdc': 'N',
  'total_amt': '12847.28',
  'unique_id': 'VAAA0022179'}]
```