# This is showing an error "Local Variable 'win' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, variables, syntax-error, variable-assignment

```
win=0

def fun():
    win+=1
    print(win)

a = 0

while True:
    if a == 0:
        fun()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refer to the variable as global inside your function, or it will assume it's local:

```
def fun():
    global win
    win+=1
```