# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ix' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to run dis code (its a little game and now im adding the graphics but it gives me the 'UnboundLocalError:' and i dont realy know what im doing wrong

```
from graphics import *

import time

import random

a = 5

c = 0

ix = 1001

x = 2

def main():



while int(ix) != int(a):

win = GraphWin('Game', 500, 500)
shape = Rectangle(Point(499,499), Point(0,0))
shape.setOutline("red")
shape.draw(win)

shape = Rectangle(Point(200, 100), Point(300, 0))
shape.setOutline("black")
shape.draw(win)


    input = Entry(Point(250, 450), 10)
    input.draw(win)

    win.getMouse()


    ix = input.getText()
    testText = Text(Point(250, 50), ix)
    testText.draw(win)
    time.sleep(1)
    testText.setText('')
main()
```

As result i expect a loop in the graphic window where when the input ix = a the loop ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [referenced before assignment error in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/referenced-before-assignment-error-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `ix` is a local variable in your `main()` function that shadows your global `ix` defined outside `main()`. To fix it you have several options:

- Define `ix` inside `main()`
- Make `ix` global with `global ix`
- Pass `ix` to the function as parameter: `main(ix)`
- Remove the `main()` function entirely and just put everything to the global scope