# Using a key in a for loop

Tags: python, pynput

I am trying to use the enter key to show different text after pressing it

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
k=0
def on_press(key):
   pass
def on_release(key):
   if key==Key.enter:
      k=k+1
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner :
  listner.join()

for i in range (10):
     print(k)
```

I dont know why it does not print anything. I'm expecting the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: Is the `for` loop inside contained inside the `with` code? The indentation looks a little off

Comment: not it s not i typed it manually

Comment: And? What is the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a "referenced before assignment" error when assigning to a global variable in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855493/why-do-i-get-a-referenced-before-assignment-error-when-assigning-to-a-global-v)

Comment: no my question is why it s not printing anything

Answer (score 1):

In Python is a concept named indentation. Other languages use for example { and }. If you want to read more on this topic, try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) link.
So your loop is not indented properly, what you can see in this error message:

```
  File "/projects/stackoverflow_70635220.py", line 11
    for i in range (10):
                        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Second, using `listener.join()` waits for the listener to terminate, what it doesn't and shouldn't do. So if you want to handle any key events, do that inside the listener functions `on_press` and `on_release`.

Furthermore, in your `on_release`-method, you are trying to increment the variable `k`. This is not possible due to the fact, that the variable is not writable in the scope of your function. If you want to learn more about scopes in python, look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/PYTHON/python_scope.asp).

You can fix the last issue by writing `global k` inside your `on_release` method.

A final code example could look something like this:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
   
k=0

def on_press(key):
    pass

def on_release(key):
    global k
    if key==Key.enter:
        k=k+1      
        print(k)
        

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener :
        listener.join()
```

Comment: there is no error but it s not working

Comment: If what you are trying to achieve is printing a number 10 times after the enter key is released, try the updated code snippet and definetively look into the two links.

Comment: @anas I updated the code snippet again to match your expectations from the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the global modifier or else you will get a `reference before assignment` error. The reason for this is that within the local scope of your on_release() function, `k=k+1` is interpreted as a reference to a local variable `k`, which doesn't exist. By using the `global` keyword you are telling python to use the `k` that exists outside of this scope.

The below code should work as you expected

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

k = 0

def on_press(key):
    pass

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.enter:
        global k
        k = k + 1

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listner:
    listner.join()

for i in range(10):
    print(k)
```

Comment: there is no error but it s not working

Comment: @anas could you explain what behavior you are expecting to see?

Comment: printing 1 ,2,3,4,5,6,7,9

Comment: @anas https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15085348/what-is-the-use-of-join-in-python-threading does this answer your question? by using .join the main thread won't resume until the `listner` has finished.

Comment: @anas Bloeckchen's updated answer should do exactly as you expect.